# Read file size from tape

Tags: linux, tar, compression, tape

I have a tape with a `.tar.lzma` archive written to it. How can I determine the size of the `.tar.lzma` archived *as is*? In other words, I'm looking to find the size of the compressed archive, *not* the size of the uncompressed `.tar` it is storing -- ideally without having to copy the archive off the tape to a disk and checking from there.

The tape in question (LTO-6) is **not** formatted with any special file system, such as LTFS.

My system is using Debian 11 Bullseye on amd64, if it is relevant to mention this.

Comment: I'm assuming "a tape with tar.lzma written to it" really means that the tape has no other structure/file system, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Correct. The tape (LTO-6) does not use LTFS or any similar configurations.

Comment: This question was referenced on [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/698593).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.tar.lzma is really just a tar file passed through the `lzma` compressor, so it really doesn't matter that it's a tar inside.

So, [lzma-file-format.txt](https://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/lzma-file-format.txt;hb=HEAD) contains all the info you need to parse that file format; it starts with a surprisingly simple header:

```
1. File Format

        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+==========================+
        |         Header          |   LZMA Compressed Data   |
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+==========================+

        The .lzma format file consist of 13-byte Header followed by
        the LZMA Compressed Data.
```

…

1.1. Header

```
    +------------+----+----+----+----+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    | Properties |  Dictionary Size  |   Uncompressed Size   |
    +------------+----+----+----+----+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

(each `+---+` is one byte, remark)

So, no compressed size info here!

You guess where this is going. https://github.com/jljusten/LZMA-SDK/blob/master/DOC/lzma-specification.txt points out that

> If "Uncompressed size" field contains ones in all 64 bits, it means that
> uncompressed size is unknown and there is the "end marker" in stream,
> that indicates the end of decoding point.
>
> In opposite case, if the value from "Uncompressed size" field is not
> equal to ((2^64) - 1), the LZMA stream decoding must be finished after
> specified number of bytes (Uncompressed size) is decoded. And if there
> is the "end marker", the LZMA decoder must read that marker also.

So, LZMA is a stream decoder that tells you

> you need to stop decompressing data after you've produced X data, or if X is 2⁶⁴-1, stop when I tell you "STOP"

So, there's no information you can use to know the length of your compressed archive other than decompressing it (discarding your decompressed data).

(That's, by the way, one of the reasons I say `tar` is a bad archive format. This would not be an issue if the compression was done within the archive container, not around it. But it's how your data is, so there's inherently nothing you can do about it...)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Are there any specific alternative archive formats you suggest would be a better choice? I can only think of `7z` but I have read this is not recommended in non-Windows environments.

Comment: 7z works fine on my linux machine :)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know tape drives and the tooling around them well enough to advise on container formats. For archival images, I personally use squashfs, but that really expects to be on a file system. It's also more on the "maximum compression at the expense of complicated creation and decompression", so I don't think it's a sensible format for linearly accessed devices.

Comment: Your feedback is much appreciated! :) I think the concerns surrounding `7z`'s usage in *nix environments is regarding permissions, or maybe extended ACLs (permissions appear to be preserved correctly in my tests).

Comment: I wonder whether you could make a good question out of this. "I encountered this problem (link to this question), and realize that in the commonly used .tar.compression archives, I'd need to read the whole archive to know its length. That's not great. Is there some Linux-available container format that's a) suitable for tape archival (ie. decompression/access must work linearly, can't jump around on a tape drive to access different parts of the same file) and b) does not have the problem described above, i.e. you can access compressed length information without decompression?"

Comment: Very good suggestion, I will create this question to find out. Cheers!