# Alternatives to compressed tarballs

Tags: linux, tar, compression, 7z, tape

I am reading/writing data from/to tapes using Debian and recently ran into an issue where I needed to figure out the size of the stored data stream, i.e. the data actually written to the tape (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/698589)). In short, using `.tar.lzma`, this does not seem to be possible without copying the entire archive off the tape first.

Are there any alternative container formats to compressed tarballs that:

- allow for determining the full size of the archive itself linearly (i.e. without shoe-shining the tape)

  - determine the size *without* reading the entire archive to disk
- allow for linear decompression/access
- are Linux-compatible (BSD-compatibility is fine too)

I think [7-Zip](https://7-zip.org/) may work in this situation, but isn't it discouraged for archival in *nix environments?

Comment: LTO tape drives support hardware compression. Are you gaining anything by sending compressed data to the tape?

Comment: Would it make sense to just write that size yourself if you can control what's written?

Comment: @doneal24 well, even in LTO-8, the compression algorithms are quite... bad, actually. they advertise getting closer to gzip, but being faster, but high speed/low compression settings of things like zstd have surpassed that years ago. So, sure, you'll lose the ability of the tape drive to autonomously compress if your entropy-code your data yourself, but if your goal ultimately is small storage size and/or fast readout, doing your own compression seems wise.

Comment: @doneal24 LTO-8 does some [360 MB/s](https://spectralogic.com/features/lto-8/) raw data rate; that's rather boring for a modern server; `zstd` [benchmarks](https://github.com/inikep/lzbench) roughly at that rate in a setting achieving a 1/3 compression ratio on a standard data set; on decompression we're talking > 1GB/s. This is bound to be even faster if you can supply zstd with a pre-generated dictionary. So, your server, with a single CPU, can compress data faster and better than your LTO-8 drive.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Makes sense. As a sysadmin I ditched tape drives around 2005. In interacting with our storage group, they are more concerned with encrypting archives before sending the data to the tapes. The encryption process is a huge bottleneck. Just didn't know if compression falls in the same category.

Comment: well, the good news is: neither the tape drives nor any better entropy coder can compress encrypted data, as a mathematical matter of fact. (good cryptography must remove correlation in the data, so that nothing can be inferred from the cipherstream, but that's exactly what a compressor uses to reduce the number of bits to store.) But if you're bounded by encryption speed, then compressing the data prior to encrypting makes a lot of sense: Less data to encrypt makes faster crypto. So, I hope your storage folks do that, or they'd be wasting both time and storage media :)